# website still logged in after logging out

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, forms-authentication

I have a website with ASP.NET Forms Authentication. I recently implement to save cookie upon user login and now I found a problem. I am not 100% if the problem persist before or not.

The steps to reproduce are:

1. go to my website with www (www.mysite.com)
2. Login to the website.
3. go to the website without www (mysite.com)
4. It would ask me to login again so I did.
5. Logout of the website. it redirect me to Login page.
6. type www.mysite.com in the address bar and I found it still login.

So accessing to my website with or without (www) become like accessing to two different website. Logging out from www.mysite.com does not logout from mysite.com. The same with logging in, and vice versa.

Login page

```
    Login1_Authenticate Handles Login1.Authenticate

     Dim result As Boolean = UserLogin(userName, password)
     If (result) Then
        e.Authenticated = True
        If Login1.RememberMeSet = True Then
            SetCookies(userName)
        End If
        LoginCounter(userName)
     Else
        e.Authenticated = False
     End If
```

SetCookies()

```
    Dim tkt As FormsAuthenticationTicket
    Dim cookiestr As String
    Dim ck As HttpCookie

    tkt = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), False, "")
    cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt)
    ck = New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName(), cookiestr)
    ck.Expires = tkt.Expiration
    ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath()
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Remove(".ASPXAUTH")
    Response.Cookies.Add(ck)

    End Sub
```

Login Status Control on Master Page

```
    LoginStatus1_LoggingOut Handles LoginStatus1.LoggingOut

    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    Session.Clear()
    Session.Abandon()
    Dim cookie1 As New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "")
    cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1)

    Dim cookie2 As New HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "")
    cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2)
```

Web.config

```
    <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies"  timeout="1440" path="/" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
```

**Solution:**  *put this in Global.asax ..*

```
     Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
     Dim fromurl As String = "http://mysite.com"
     Dim tourl As String = "http://www.mysite.com"
     If HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains(fromurl) Then
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", tourl)
     End If
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the session cookie is (sub)domain specific.

You need to redirect all requests from one domain to the other to force the browser to only use one session.

Comment: On your home page, if `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]` matches one domain,  

`response.Redirect("http://www.otherdomain.com", false);`
or
`response.RedirectPermanent("http://www.otherdomain.com", false);` if you want google to ONLY index your other domain.

Comment: Hi Greg ... it does the job .. but raising another issue to the website .. normally, if the user type the url, eg. www.mysite.com it shows nothing but just that url. Now, if the user type, mysite.com, it redirects to www.mysite.com/default.aspx ... revealing the page name to the website .. I understand this is not a major issue however I don't wish this to happen ... is there any other way around ? Thanks

Comment: This link may help with that, but you're opening up another can of worms: [redirecting default.aspx to root](http://swortham.blogspot.com/2008/12/redirecting-default-page-defaultaspx-to.html)

Comment: Hi Greg, the new problem fixed by using this instead of response.Redirect ... Thanks I will mark your post as answer and close the question .. HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently" HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", tourl)